# How to create "variables" for later search and replace (sort of like a merge-field in HTML

Tags: html, variables

I use a lot (20 or so) of what FrontPage 2003 (don't laugh!) calls "Site Parameters", which are essentially variables. I use them for the Number of Products, Phone Hours, etc.

I'm upgrading to Expression Web, which does not support changing or adding those Parameters. Also, I'd like to create Variables for our Breadcrumbs trail.  (So a product page might have breadcrumbs:   Products> This Product> Screenshot.
So if we ever decide to rename Products I want to easily be able to replace it.

What I do not want to do:

- Replace the value when the page is served up. That slows things down a bit and forces all pages to be .aspx, etc. I want to stick with plain html.
- Replace the value using Javascript (same reason, and a tiny % of brrowsers don't have .js enabled).

**I was thinking:**

```
we have <variable.products_count>20</variable.products_count>
```

**But**..... it's easy to get another tag and text in there, as happens in this example:

```
<variable.products_count> we have <strong>20</strong>  </variable.products_count>
```

Now when I replace, I'm replacing the  tags and "we have" as well.

Comment: Does your solution need to remain inside _Expression Web_? Doing string search-and-replace is pretty trivial with a giant pile of tools -- if you don't mind adding a new step to your publish process.

Comment: No, it does not *have* to stay in EW.  But, Opps, My example wasn't clear.  Take a look at the updated "I was thinking".  I don't see how any search and replace could discern that "we have" (which got moved during editing) is not really part of <variable.products>

Comment: reconsider about your javascript options. You can use knockout.js , which allows  DOM elements (such as text) to be updated when a observable view model javascript object changes value.

Answer (score 3):

> What I do not want to do: Replace the value when the page is served up. That slows things down a bit and forces all pages to be .aspx, etc. I want to stick with plain html.

Technically you are correct; there will probably be a performance hit by using an executed versus static page. But the overhead of inserting a few dynamic values is so trivial that it shouldn't even factor into the decision making process.

At it's simplest:

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div>Good old HTML</div>
    <div>A dynamic value: <%= SiteParameters.Foo %></div>
</body>
```

### c# (or VB.Net, or whatever you prefer)

```
public static class SiteParameters 
{
    // This value could be pulled from a config file, a database, etc.
    public static readonly string Foo = "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example with the *we have* problem can be easily re-written to fix the problem:

```
<variable.products_count> we have <strong>20</strong>  </variable.products_count>
```

to:

```
we have <strong><variable.products_count></variable.products_count></strong>
```

Of course, I think the *easier* approach is to step slightly outside of HTML syntax and pick variable names that are unlikely to occur in your documentation:

```
we have <strong>@@PRODUCTS_COUNT@@</strong> ...
```

When you have several of these you can replace them all with one pass of a simple text-replacement tool such as `sed(1)`:

```
sed -e 's/@@PRODUCTS_COUNT@@/20/g'
    -e 's/@@PRODUCTS@@/Products/g'
    -e 's/@@SCREENSHOTS@@/Screen Shots/g' < inputfile > output.html
```

To automate over many files, you'd probably want to write a little script:

```sed
s/@@PRODUCTS_COUNT@@/20/g;
s/@@PRODUCTS@@/Products/g;
s/@@SCREENSHOTS@@/Screen Shots/g;
```

and run it on all your files:

```sh
for f in pre/*.html ; do sed -f /path/to/script < "$f" > "${f/pre/post}" ; done
```

(The `${f/pre/post}` replaces the `pre` with `post`; your post-processed files would be in the `post/` directory.)